# No me aparece opción RUN FILE en netbeans cuando creo una API con spring

Tags: netbeans, spring

Tengo un problema, cuando sigo los pasos para crear la API con SpringBoot y al último cuando me posiciono sobre la clase Main para ejecutarla y verificar en la consola de salida sobre qué URL y puerto levanta el servidor web, hago click derecho y no me aparece la opción "run file". Adjunto foto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué pasa si usas uno de los botones "play" que están ahí justo encima?

Comment: busca la rama Main para ejecutar, tarda muchisimo y no hace nada.

Comment: ¿Intentaste abriendo `Application.java` y en el método `main` hacer click derecho >  `Run File`?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: es lo que hice en la imagen